# curl failure using pdal.Reader.ept

Tags: lidar

I am trying to use Reader.ept to access data via a URL.

The URL works fine and I can visualize the number of points in the polygon. However when I try to use a pipeline to access the points and generate a surface, I get a curl failure. I am using PDAL in a Jupyter notebook following this https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JQpcVFFJYMrJCfodqP4Nc_B0_w6p5WOV?usp=sharing#scrollTo=wQtbyo9bgeOa

Code below

```py
for index, row in tiles_mec.iterrows():
    
    id = row ['tile_id']
    
    resolution = 1
    useful_classes = "Classification[0:6],Classification[17:17],Classification[9:9],Classification[10:10],Classification[11:11],Classification[2:2]"
    
    #fetch all points and create full dsm
    reader = pdl.Reader.ept(url, 
                         resolution=resolution, 
                         polygon = row['geometry'].wkt)
    rng = pdl.Filter.range(limits=useful_classes)
    z = pdl.Writer.gdal(out_fdsm + id +"_rfdsm_r1.tif", 
                    resolution=resolution, 
                    dimension="Z", 
                    data_type="float32", 
                    output_type="mean",
                    nodata=-9999)

    pipeline = reader | rng | z
    pipeline.execute()
```

Error:

> Curl failure: Timeout was reached

Comment: Can you tell some details about the curl failure?

Comment: "Curl failure: Timeout was reached"
Just this

Comment: Please include exact error message and a code snippet in the body of your question.

Comment: Linking to external sites for code is ok as long as you include a relevant snippet in your question. Not everyone can access external code and it can change or disappear rendering the question useless.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a warning that was being emitted by PDAL when it was retrying its fetches. You can ignore it.

It should have been fixed in PDAL 2.6.0.

Comment: It will be fixed in 2.6.1 by this https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/pull/4253